# Should I have problem with connection to internet from iphone phonegap app through 3G or EDGE?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have an app written in javascript/html/css and using phonegap framework. For javascript ajax I use jQuery.ajax(). App work fine when there is wifi connection but doesn't work when there is 3G or EDGE. Does anyone know if there is something I can do to make it work seamlessly?

Answer (score 1):

To trouble-shoot, use [PhoneGap's Reachability API](http://wiki.phonegap.com/iPhone%3A-Reachability-API-use) to gauge your connection, whether its wi-fi, 3g/edge, whether you have an internet connection, your server is reachable etc.

The UIWebView does not differentiate what type of connection you have, its all transparent (at least it should...)

Answer (score 0):

The means you are connected to the internet should not make a difference, unless the size of the datafile(s) you are transferring are too large for fast transit via 3G or EDGE.